# how to identify which servlet called by which jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've a URL pattern like `webroot/TellSomeoneMail` and corresponding class,

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>TellSomeoneMail</servlet-name>
      <display-name>Tell Someone Mail</display-name>
      <servlet-class>com.nightingale.register.servlet.TellSomeoneMailServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
```

but how to identify which JSP file calling this servlet?

Comment: i've thoudands of jsp files.

Comment: but i dont know file name?

Comment: Do yo mean "which jsp file is calling this servlet" or "which jsp file is this servlet calling" ? Because it it really not the same...

Comment: which jsp file is this servlet is this..

Comment: You want to figure it out from within JSP page during execution or to find all JSP files in your project containing reference to webroot/TellSomeoneMail?

Comment: i want only which jsp file call this servlet right now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify during execution into our servlet by looking to the referer header in the HTTP body:

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

**Edit 1**: You can also use session to keep the last url acceded by the user (such mechanism is already present in framework like grails or Spring under the "flash" attribute, not to be confused with adobe flash). If you use simple Servlet / JSP, you need to code such support...

**Edit 2** Last solution if cookie and referee is blocked, is to add a parameter in the URL with reference to the last page, for instance `URL?from=home_pg` or `URL?from=/homepage.html` but it could require rewriting of urls embedded in the page.

Comment: The referrer header can always be blocked.

Comment: @DeepakBala i'm unable to understandur comment. if blocked then what is the solution.

Comment: @DeepakBala I've edited my answer with an alternative methods using session / cookie or URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the URL from which the request was sent. Take a look at the following code

```
if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
    String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find JSP pages that allow the user to make requests to  your servlet : Check the path the servlet is mapped under in the `<servlet-mapping>` element(s) in web.xml.

Then do a full text search on all the JSP's in your projet for this string. Look for HTML `<a>` and `<form>` element with target containing your servlet path.